# Touching emotionally

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, word-request, verbs

In English or Finnish I can say that I was touched by something or an experience was touching, meaning that I was touched emotionally, not physically.
How can I express the same in Latin?
Does *tangere* work this way, or should I use some other verb or perhaps other kind of word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly you may use *tangere*, though in this situation it and other verbs (*moveo, commoveo, afficio, pelli* and so on) usually have some sort of qualification:

*amore puellae pelli* ; *amore fraterni commotus erat*; etc.

This type of usage is actually quite common. And (of course!) it applies to emotions other than love:

*pudore affixus est*.

I have made up the examples. I hope that's sufficient explanation, without the need to quote actual instances?

Comment: +1, especially for *commotus*. *Vehementer commotus* would be a great way of saying, "I was very touched."

Comment: First, could you explain the intended meaning of *amore puellae pelli* and give a classical citation or two confirming this usage? I only find the verb in collocations with *animum/mentem* and anything but tender emotions. And second, the PPP of *afficere* is *affectus*, yours means "arrested, nailed by shame, as in to the spot"  :-)

Comment: As I said, the examples are made up. _Pelli_ is the passive infinitive of _pello_ and _affixus is not from _afficio_, but from _affigo_. Sorry about the slight confusion!

Answer (score 3):

I offer a quote from the *Laudato Si* encyclical, an official document of the Vatican (the country where Latin is, well, the official language). [In English](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/encyclicals/documents/papa-francesco_20150524_enciclica-laudato-si.html), it says:

> With **moving** tenderness he [Jesus] would remind them [his disciples] that each one of them is important in God’s eyes

The [Latin version](http://w2.vatican.va/content/francesco/la/encyclicals/documents/papa-francesco_20150524_enciclica-laudato-si.html) says:

> atque ipsis **moventi** blandimento memorabat quomodo suos ob oculos unaquaeque earum magnum habeat pondus

Thus, *moventi*, from the adjective *[movens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/movens#Latin)*, seems to be the word you are looking for. Wiktionary translate it exactly as "moving".

Comment: Motus in all its meanings (noun, adjective, participle) also comes to mind as idiomatic

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, I would use the verb *moveō*, or one of its derivatives. This can either take the emotion/result as its direct object (*movet lacrimās* "it moved [me] to tears"), or a metonymy like *animum*; when a person is the object, the verb is more often in the passive (*movetur verbīs* "he was moved by these words").

*Moveō* itself certainly works, but *commoveō* can be used for added intensity, and *permoveō* was seldom used for anything except this meaning (i.e. it almost never meant literal motion).

Answer (score 2):

The figurative use of tango "to touch, move, affect, impress" is very common in Latin. You can find lots of examples in L/S, s.v. "tango II A", or in any other Latin dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

For fiercely tragic emotions:

**plango, plangere, planxi, planctum.** means both strike, hit;  and bewail, cry, lament.
(Cicero and Virgil)